# How to solve the error in writing to a text file

Tags: python, text-files, filenames

When I run the following code, instead of creating a text file in my working directory with the name `'03/08/2020.txt'`, it generates an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '03/08/2020.txt'`. As far as I think, it is just because of the slashes.
But anyhow, I want to create a text file with slashes because this thing is a part of a large code and I have to work with dates (for attendance purposes).

```
dates = ['03/08/2020', '1', '2', '3']
def test(alist):
    myfile = open(alist[0])+'.txt', 'w')
    for i in alist:
        myfile.write(f"{i}\n")
myfile.close()
test(dates)
```

is there a way yo handle this issue?

Comment: Fix the fourth line, it should be `myfile = open(alist[0] + '.txt', 'w')`. You put an unnecessary parenthesis there

Comment: You are going to run into a bunch of issues either now or later if you try to use slashes in your file names. Use hyphens instead. `03-08-2020.txt`

Comment: The last line of the function is incorrectly indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jdaz said, you can instead use "03-08-2020.txt"

This is because on windows, you can't add to the following characters to your file names:

```
\ / : * ?  " < > |
```

If you try to rename a file with one of those characters, you'll see a message saying you can't do so.